# Changing thanks to endnotes

Tags: footnotes, titles, article, endnotes, front-matter

I would like to convert the front matter thanks footnote to an endnote.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\author{%
  Abraham Lincoln%
  \thanks{1600 Pennsylvania Ave., Washington, D.C.}%
  \thanks{Deceased}%
}
\title{First Inaugural Address}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]\footnote{This is not really Latin.} \lipsum[2]\footnote{Nor is it Lincoln.} 
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the full functionality of `\thanks`, with multiple authors denoted with different symbols, then this approach works.

If you just need a single author, and you don't need symbols, you could just `\let\thanks\endnote`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote\endnote % convert \footnotes to \endnotes

% Set up the symbols used in \thanks 
% Copied directly from LaTeX \@fnsymbol
\newcommand{\ensymbol}[1]{%
    \ensuremath{\ifcase#1\or *\or \dagger\or \ddagger\or 
    \mathsection\or \mathparagraph\or \|\or **\or \dagger\dagger 
    \or \ddagger\ddagger \else\@ctrerr\fi}%
}

% Redefine thanks as an endnote using symbols instead of numbers
\renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\theendnote}{\ensymbol{\value{endnote}}}%
    \endnote{#1}%
}

% Redefine \maketitle so that it resets the endnote counter after the
% \thanks notes
\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{%
    \oldmaketitle
    \setcounter{endnote}{0}%
}

\author{%
    Abraham Lincoln%
    \thanks{1600 Pennsylvania Ave., Washington, D.C.}%
    \thanks{Deceased}%
}
\title{First Inaugural Address}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum[1]\footnote{This is not really Latin.}
\lipsum[2]\footnote{Nor is it Lincoln.}
\lipsum[3]

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]